# Not able to call javascript function from index.html

Tags: javascript, html, function, file, load

HI i am facing some problem while calling function from index.html on load event
it return error readjson is not defined in console.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(window).load(function () {   
readjson('a','s');
});
</script>
```

main.js file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function readjson(val1,val2){
//some code
}

</script>
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not able to call, i have link main.js file to index.html

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript files shouldn't include any HTML.

Remove `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` from `main.js`.

You should see an error when that file is loaded (along the lines of Unexpected token `<`).

Comment: This is true. I didn't catch this.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this inside the js file without the "script" tag :

```
function readjson(val1,val2){
//some code
}
```

In index.html you need the "script"

And follow the advice given in the comments, always include first the .js file and then the function in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jquery link properly?? 
If not, you should add jquery link for $(window) to be called. such as..

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: It would error on `$` being undefined before it even got to the attempt to call `readjson` is that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have two script declarations as you are showing here the the window load will fire first. It then look for your function, which has not been created yet. That's why you are getting undefined.

You could have one script declaration on the page and place your function in the load function.

```
<script>

$(window).load(function () {   

readjson('a','s');

function readjson(val1,val2){
//some code
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: No. The load event would not trigger until the other script was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Remove tags from main.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> and </script>
```

and remember to include jquery and main.js with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```